# How to convert String to IWorkspace in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I am creating a plugin project to analyse the java projects in Eclipse workspace.I want to get the current location of the Eclipse workspace through another way.Instead of using `IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();`But I want to use this code for getting the location of eclipse workspace:
`URL location = Current_class.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
 String workspaceLoc = ordinalIndexOf(location.getFile());`

I have to somehow convert String to IWorkSpace object.I tried using this code.

```
fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(new URL(workspaceLoc)); 
 IWorkspace workspace =(IWorkspace)fileUrl;
```

But an error is there.

```
Cannot cast from URL to IWorkspace
```

Can anyone give suggestions on how to do it?I am really stuck at this.

Comment: The doc for IWorkspace says "There is only one workspace per running platform", so I'm not clear what workspace you're trying to obtain, there is only one anyway.

Comment: During running plugin project in eclipse, if i use the code 'workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();'  the var workspace is shown as 'F:/runtime-EclipseApplication' but actually it should have been 'F:/MecWorkspace'. So i used the other code to get this particular location in string and trying to convert it to IWorkspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. The `IWorkspace` object is created during Eclipse startup and can't be created any other way.

The `Platform.getInstanceLocation()` method gives you the location of the current workspace.

Note that when you use 'Run as Eclipse Application' to test your plugin a new instance of Eclipse is started which uses a new workspace. The only way to access your development workspace is to install the plugin in to your main Eclipse installation. You should create projects in the test workspace to do your testing with.

Comment: This code is also giving workspace as 'F:/runtime-EclipseApplication' but actually my eclipse workpace is ''F:/MecWorkspace'.The above solution is not working!

Comment: When you run a plugin from within Eclipse it creates a new instance of Eclipse with a new workspace - which is what you are seeing. You would have to install the plugin in to your Eclipse to access your development workspace.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot @greg-449 .I got my confusion cleared. I have installed the plugin in Eclipse as you told.But now only problem is that i cant debug my plugin as it is already being deployed.

Comment: For development you should create projects in the test workspace containing whatever it is you want to test.

Comment: Is test workspace different from the development workspace ? If so, then how can i create a test workspace?I am new in PDE so i dont know much.

Comment: The "test" workspace is one you already ran across: `F:/runtime-EclipseApplication` . You're debugging a separate running copy of Eclipse with its own workspace at that point, so you can make whatever changes and create any projects you need to in there.